# Initializing Eigen ArrayXd inside std::vector causes crash

Tags: c++, eigen

I need to set up a `std::vector` of Eigen arrays. However, trying to initialize them causes a crash.

Example:

```
std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd> data( 12 );

for ( unsigned i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
  data[i] = Eigen::ArrayXd( 32964, 0 );
}
```

I get the following assertion failure:

```
Assertion failed: (!(RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || 
(rows==RowsAtCompileTime)) && (!(ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || 
(cols==ColsAtCompileTime)) && (!(RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && 
MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows<=MaxRowsAtCompileTime)) && 
(!(ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || 
(cols<=MaxColsAtCompileTime)) && rows>=0 && cols>=0 && "Invalid sizes when 
resizing a matrix or array.", file eigen\Eigen\src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h, 
line 285
```

Comment: `Eigen::ArrayXd( 32964, 0 )` tries to create a `32964 x 0`-sized array. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @chtz You're right, I was mixing up STL and Eigen notation, should have been Eigen::ArrayXd::Zero(32964). Thanks.